# Why NSAssert1, etc instead of NSAssert?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsassert

I thought `NSAssert` couldn't use `printf` specifiers, but this:

```
NSAssert(0, @"%@%@", @"foo", @"bar");
```

works just as you'd expect:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[MyClass myMethod], <Path>/MyClass.m:84
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
    reason: 'foobar'
```

So what's the point of using `NSAssert1`, `NSAssert2`, etc when `NSAssert` works?

This with Xcode 4.0 and the iOS 4.3 SDK, if that matters. (If it doesn't, I'll update the tags.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Current versions of `NSAssert()` use preprocessor variadic macros, i.e., `__VA_ARGS__`. Since variadic macros are a C99 feature, my guess is that older versions of the SDK didn’t allow variable arguments in `NSAssert()`, hence the need for `NSAssert1()`, `NSAssert2()`, etc.

If you try to compile

```
NSAssert(0, @"%@%@", @"foo", @"bar");
```

using `-std=c89` or `-ansi` (ISO C90, an older version of C that doesn’t support variadic macros), you get a compiler error:

```
error: too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation
    NSAssert(0, @"%@%@", @"foo", @"bar");
```

For that code to compile with `-std=c89` or `-ansi`, you need to use `NSAssert2()`:

```
NSAssert2(0, @"%@%@", @"foo", @"bar");
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent Answer By Bavarious.

Just adding my single bit to it.
For the people who are facing issue `Too many arguments provided to function-like macro invocation`.
Pay attention to the part mentioned as `-std=c89` by @Bavarious.

Here is how I got rid of the issue.

1. Go to build settings -> Apple LLVM 6.1
2. Find C language dialect
3. Change to `-std=c99`